# Is it possible with SQLAlchemy to share SQLite database among multiple Python processes?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

Is it possible to share an in memory SQLite database using SQLAlchemy among multiple Python processes? All applications are reading and writing from/to it. If so, is it desirable?

Answer (score 1):

No, you *cannot* share an in-memory SQLite database between processes. An in-memory SQLite database is private to the *connection* that created it; even within the same process, a new connection to `:memory:` creates a new database. SQLAlchemy does not lift this limitation.

You can only share a file-based database. SQLite uses as [system of locking](http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html) to make that possible.

That said, SQLite is not the best choice for concurrent database access. A database using a separate server to manage multiple clients (such as MySQL or PostgreSQL) is a better choice if performance is an issue.